# Upgrade is interrupted and my Ubuntu system is somewhere between 11 and 12

Tags: installation, upgrade, dual-boot

My upgrade have been interrupted with the following terminal warning. I tried to re-upgrade my system for many times, but the same thing kept occurring.

the last 4 lines in terminal (during upgrade):

```
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on dev/sda2
Skipping Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on Wubi system
```

done

after these lines, the upgrade is not continuing.

Answer (score 0):

These lines appear to be output from grub setup and are not warnings or errors, can you give some more lines before or after? What command is being used to upgrade? and to re - upgrade?

A few times when my upgrade was interrupted i was able to recover with something like

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(the correct command should show up when u try to do `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`. More information can be found [here](http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/).